# get google place bounding box from google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-places-api, bounds

i want to get google place bounding box.
i am getting viewports by using google places api but viewports do not give desired co-ordinates, actually i want to trigger some function when user entered in place, e.g when user enter in hotel

this is what i am doing

```
Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(googleApiClientPlaces, "dummyPlaceID").setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceBuffer places)
                        {
                            if (places.getStatus().isSuccess() && places.getCount() > 0)
                            {
                                Place place = places.get(0);
                                LatLngBounds latLngBounds = place.getViewport();

                                // check is user withing place bounds 
                                /*if(currentLocation.within(latLngBounds))
                                {
                                     // do something
                                }*/
                            }
                            places.release();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "enter"?

Comment: i mean when a person go in hotel then i need to trigger some function

Comment: @JonasKöritz did you get it

Comment: You will have to determine at which location the user is most probably. And determine the probability of being correct depending on the circumstances like GPS signal quality etc.

Comment: If this is targeted at a few specific buildings you have access to, use BT LE Beacons to detect them.

Comment: i am getting user location rightly, i just need to get the area (boundary) of a place (hotel). e.g i have placeID of hotel, i need some api which gives me area of that place

Comment: I dont think this such an API is available. You will have to check which location the user is closest to.